# MSAccess Error: Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

Tags: ms-access, vba

The issue is that it's looking for the OLE Automation reference in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb

Which is fine for 64bit users but not for 32bit.
How would I fix this?

How do I find out if the reference is used anywhere?
I'm afraid of simply removing the reference then finding out it's being used somewhere.

Update: Below is where the error is triggered:

```
  Error -->  Set Cnxn = New ADODB.Connection
         With Cnxn
           .Provider = "MSDataShape"
           .Properties("Data Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB"
           .Properties("Data Source").Value = dbserver
           .Properties("User ID").Value = username
           .Properties("Password").Value = password
           .Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = dbname
           .CommandTimeout = 120
           .ConnectionTimeout = 120
           .Open
        End With
```

Comment: Late binding should work fine, I think. `Set Cnxn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All references are pointing to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and therefore causing the errors on 32 bit machines.

I opened the Access app on a 32bit machine and re-added the all the references that were previously pointing to the SysWOW64 folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

shld check the service pack of windows 7. SP1 gives an error. should compile in a later or previous service pack.